# Port Error - Visual Studio 2022: Azure Function - Port 7071 is unavailable

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting below error while debugging two Azure function locally in visual studio 2022

```
Port 7071 is unavailable. Close the process using that port, or specify another port using --port [-p].
```

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2022, the fix is slightly different.

Open project properties and then go to Debug -> Open debug launch profiles UI.

Input  the following line with the port you want to use:

```
host start --port 11000
```

[image]

The above fix works for .NET 6 Azure functions that runs as Project instead of isolated process